# Intellij Idea Find Tool Window max column length override

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

In Intellij (v 13), I'm doing a file search (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) for Occurrences of 'this.is.a.fake.key' in Project with mask '*.properties'.

Specifically, I'm searching for property keys, so that I can derive their values in my search results.  The search executes fine, but the problem is the results that are returned in the Find Tool Window are truncated if the lines being returned are greater than 200 characters in length.

How can I configure the Find Tool Window to change this default setting to say 400 characters, as I need the entire line of text for the matched results.  Here's an example of the Exported search:

```
Targets
Occurrences of 'this.is.a.fake.key' in Module 'proj' with mask '*.properties'
Found Occurrences  (2 usages found)
    Unclassified occurrence  (2 usages found)
    proj  (2 usages found)
          (2 usages found)
            simple_resource_bundle.properties  (2 usages found)
                (1405: 1) this.is.a.fake.key.with.less.than.two.hundred.characters=All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.   All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.   All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.
                (1406: 1) this.is.a.fake.key
```

The following is what the property file contains:

```
this.is.a.fake.key.with.less.than.two.hundred.characters=All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.   All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.   All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.
this.is.a.fake.key.with.more.than.two.hundred.characters=All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.   All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.   All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.
```

Comment: what do you mean, 'derive their value in my search results'? Why does it matter that the results are truncated to 200 chars?

Comment: I need the keys' values, in the results, so I can export it.  It matters because I can't export it if the values are truncated.

Comment: Given the file and line number you could extract the actual line from the file using a script that parses the saved search results.

Comment: Please create an issue on youtrack. It is clearly behaving badly.

Answer (score 0):

[You cannot, unless you change this class.](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/usageView/src/com/intellij/usages/ChunkExtractor.java#L59-59)